# How to call a function from header file in c++

Tags: c++

I'm new in C++
I was using java before,  I'm trying to call a function in c++ from a hearder file.

Here is my code:

sum.h

```
int sum(int a, int b);
```

cur_time.h

```
#ifndef CUR_TIME_H
#define CUR_TIME_H

clock_t clock(void);

#endif  /* CUR_TIME_H */
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sum.h"
#include "cur_time.h"

int main ()
{
  int x;
  int y;

  x = sum(3,4);
  std::cout << x;

  y = clock(void);
  y = std::cout << y;
  return 0;
}
```

So in main.cpp I try to display the elapsed time of my system with this function: `clock_t clock(void);`

When I run the project, I have this error:

```
main.cpp:13:13: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
main.cpp:14:3: error: ‘__ostream_type’ was not declared in this scope
```

If I run the code without calling the second function it works for sum.

Comment: Where is "another class", which is in the title?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Maxtron. This smells like homework, which is rather like blood in water to sharks around here at times, just a warning. A few things to keep in mind, to avoid getting bit by some of the less patient members, especially in future posts: 1) Assume you'll write all the code yourself. We usually only point you in the right direction. 2) Do some research prior. Do you know what your two error messages mean? They may well be cryptic in your context, but you should understand their meaning anyhow. Research before posting 3) Experiment, and then describe What Have You Tried.

Answer (score 2):

- You don't have to (and mustn't) use `void` in parentheses on calling a function.
- assigning `std::cout << y` to `y` is meaningless here and gcc gave me this error:

  > error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::basic_ostream' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Therefore, main.cpp should be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sum.h"
#include "cur_time.h"

int main ()
{
  int x;
  int y;

  x = sum(3,4);
  std::cout << x;

  y = clock(); // remove void
  std::cout << y; // remove y = 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot MikeCAT but it ignores to display the value of x i got only Y

Comment: @MikeCAT, code-only answers aren't generally helpful to the community at large. Please add explanation as to WHY this is the solution. That way, A) the OP understands the underlying logic and learns something, and B) other readers can better apply this to their code and their unique version of the problem.

Comment: @Maxtron Really? This code properly printed both `x` and `y` on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yIypRsRKL3FVKXr7).

Comment: @MikeCAT no it displays only the value of x

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your `sum(int, int)` function in `Sum.h`?

Simply doing `int sum(int a, int b);` is not good enough, you need to define that function.

```
int sum(int x, int y) {return x+y;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take that first error message as a clue. I encounter it a LOT, in various forms, when I write C++ code.

> main.cpp:13:13: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’

The phrase "expected primary-expression" almost always means that you have A) forgotten something, or B) typed something weird or unexpected.

For example, you will get the same kind of error if you were to try `cout << "Hello, " < "world!" << endl;` In that case, I put a `<` where I should have put a `<<`. (Actual example from my code two days ago.)

In your case, the error message is screaming about `void`, which means that `void` or whatever precedes it is out of place. In your line `y = clock(void);`, we know that the preceding token `(` is correct...we're calling a function after all. That must mean that `void` is mistyped or out of place. Obviously it isn't mistyped. If you drop it, your code works.

What's up with that? Well, unlike some languages, C++ can accept an empty arg list, so long as the function wasn't expecting any arguments. `y = clock();` will properly call the function.

[**BONUS:** If you're trying to call a *constructor* without any arguments, leave off the parenthesis altogether in the call. It's just one of those weird exceptions.]

So, what about that second error? In general, you should try to fix only the error at the top of the list (unless you know for certain what the other(s) are about). Many times, one error causes other weirder errors to happen as well. To see what I mean, try leaving off a semicolon and check out the errors you get as a result. Fix that error and recompile. If the second error shows up again, THEN you address it.

---

In regards to your comment to MikeCAT, this is a separate issue, but I'll address it the same anyway. Your `clock()` function returns `clock_t`, but you are assigning it to `y`, which is of type `int`. It appears that `clock_t` is based on `int`, so you should be able to get away with it. However, it may be a good idea to switch `y` to type `clock_t` as well, and see if that resolves it.

Beyond that, it may have to do with how you're using clock, though I'm not an expert on that class. If you continue to have problems, create a new question. On StackOverflow, you want to stick to ONE problem in ONE question. :)

(See my comment to your question for some additional tips on surviving and thriving around here.)

Comment: why wasitng your time to explain in so many lines i already resolved my problem Thank you.

Comment: It isn't a waste at all. A) I don't know your experience level, so I am giving you additional tools for solving this and similar problems. B) I'm answering for anyone else who will find this question later, so they can similarly solve this TYPE of problem. C) When I first posted this, it wasn't clear the problem was solved yet. It is common for there to be multiple answers to one question on StackOverflow, as there are multiple ways to solve and explain problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation